# Alternating between forms in c#

Tags: c#

I have 6 forms. 3 forms are for information which are forms 4-6 these forms function is just a basic open and close. Then there are forms 1-3 all have menu strip which connects to forms 4-6. Form 1 is the initial page which opens either form 2 or 3 depending on what button you click. Form 2 opens form 3 upon button click and form 3 has an option to open form 2.

My problem now is I have a null reference exception everytime I open form 2 from form 3.

Form 2 codes:

```
    Form3 game = new Form3();
    Form4 oneplayer = new Form4();
    Form5 twoplayer = new Form5();
    Form6 creditpage = new Form6();

    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void exitToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }

    private void onePlayerToolStripMenuItem1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        oneplayer.Show();
    }

    private void twoPlayerToolStripMenuItem1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        twoplayer.Show();
    }

    private void creditToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        creditpage.Show();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Hide();
        game.Show();
    }
```

Form 3 codes:

```
    Form2 choice;
    Form4 oneplayer = new Form4();
    Form5 twoplayer = new Form5();
    Form6 creditpage = new Form6();

    public Form3()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void twoPlayerToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        choice.Show();
        this.Close();
    }

    private void exitToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }

    private void onePlayerToolStripMenuItem1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        oneplayer.Show();
    }

    private void twoPlayerToolStripMenuItem1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        twoplayer.Show();
    }

    private void creditToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        creditpage.Show();
    }
```

New to this. Please forgive me :P

Comment: Where Is The Question Or The Problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't setting the form to anything:

```
Form2 choice;   // <===== Here
Form4 oneplayer = new Form4();
Form5 twoplayer = new Form5();
Form6 creditpage = new Form6();
```

Comment: I removed the new Form2() from that line since it creates a infinite looping error

Comment: @Don Well not it's creating a `NullReferenceException`.

Comment: @Don The reason you were previously getting an infinite loop is that `Form2` creates a `Form3` when it's constructed & `Form3` creates a `Form2` when it is constructed; thus you have perpetual construction from one to the other etc.  To fix this, don't construct all your objects up front, just construct them when you need to.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a method in form3 like this:

```
 public void setForm2 (Form2 choice_)
    {
        choice = choice_;
    }
```

and add this line to your button1.click

```
game.setForm2(this);
```